# I'm a Legendary Story so who am I?

Tags: riddle

First riddle I made, hope it's not too easy nor too hard:

> Some people think I'm an alien;
>   my father murdered his brother.
>   Some made many sacrifices for me,
>   and my mother is very protective.
>   I never had kids, I was always too busy with work.
>   I'm a legendary story.
>   If you come to me, I will test you.

**Question**: Who am I?

**Hint 1**:

> People made statue(s) of me

**Hint 2**:

> Bruce Willis

**Hint 3**:

> Some people think my whole family were aliens.

Comment: I added 2 hints because it might be to harsh to start with at first.

Comment: "not because my father murdered his brother" means "my father murdered his brother but this is not the reason why people think I'm an alien" or "my father didn't kill his brother"?

Comment: @lelloman if it's hard to understand I removed ' not because' It's just his father murdered his brother.

Comment: thanks, the doubt arose because of the explanation in the answer below, "not a son of.."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure about this, but I though it was worth giving a shot.
Answer:

> [Anubis](http://www.egyptianmyths.net/anubis.htm)

Some people think I'm an alien,

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_astronaut_hypothesis

not because my father murdered his brother,

> My theory may fall over here.  Anubis was the "biological" son of [Nephthys](http://www.egyptianmyths.net/nephthys.htm) and [Osiris](http://www.egyptianmyths.net/osiris.htm), but Nephthys was actually [Seth](http://www.egyptianmyths.net/seth.htm)'s wife and the 3 of them were brothers (sick, I know) and Seth killed Osiris. So (if this wasn't twisted enough) Anubis' step father killed his brother (Osiris).

some made many sacrifices for me,

> back in those days people sacrificed about anything for any god in any mythology

and my mother is very protective,

> His mother was [Nephthys](http://www.ancientegypt.co.uk/gods/explore/nephthys.html) the protective goddess of the dead

I never had kids, I was always to busy with work,

> Well, he didn't have kids and had a full time job. Actually 3 of them.   "Anubis had three important functions. He supervised the embalming of bodies. He received the mummy into the tomb and performed the Opening of the Mouth ceremony and then conducted the soul in the Field of Celestial Offerings. Most importantly though, Anubis monitored the Scales of Truth to protect the dead from deception and eternal death."

I'm a legendary story,

> He is a character in the Egyptian Mythology

If you come to me, I will test you.

> as stated above he monitored the "Scales of Truth": The scale of truth in Egyptian mythology found the balance between the deceased human's heart and the feather of truth. If the feather was heavier, they went on to the next test and/or stage of their passage. If the heart was heavier, it would be eaten by a monster at the base of the scale, and the soul of the person would wander aimlessly forever

Hint 1:

> *People made statue(s) of me.*
>  there are a lot of Anubis statues in Egypt.

Hint 2:

> *Bruce Willis*
>  Correct answer here is: Jackal, Anibus his animal sign is Jackal.  (added by OP).

Hint 3:

> *Some people think my whole family were aliens.*
>  Same as the answer for the first line.

Comment: Correct on the 2e hint is wrong. It's a different movie, I'll edit the correct answer in. so I don't spoil it in the comments :-)

Comment: Give me 2 more minutes...I think I know it

Comment: Perfect that's the good answer to hint 2 :)

Comment: I can't edit it anymore because when I click edit I can see your edit, but if it's worth something, I got it right.

Comment: Yea I edited it before you wrote give me 2 minutes :x
Can't you rollback or something or overedit? Anyways you had it!

Comment: Hey, everyone makes mistakes :(

Comment: I know @Seth, but your own brother? :)

Comment: What? No Stargate reference? ;)

Comment: @Marius Still better than eating your own children (Chronos) :/

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are:

> Jesus Christ

Some people think I'm an alien,

> Ancient Astronaut theory

not because my father murdered his brother,

> Not a son of Cain

some made many sacrifices for me,

> Lots and lots of examples of religious people making sacrifices for their religion

and my mother is very protective,

> Christians pray to St. Mary for protection

I never had kids, I was always to busy with work,

> I guess I didn't hear anything about Jesus having children, but I'm not sure about this one, and he was a carpenter so that might have kept him busy while not teaching stuff or performing miracles.

I'm a legendary story,

> It is, depending on your beliefs.

If you come to me, I will test you.

> Last Judgement

HINT 1

> There are many statues of Jesus

HINT 2

> Bruce Willis' character died in movie Armageddon to save humanity which can be loosely connected to Jesus dying for humanity on the cross.

Comment: Nice answer but it's not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: "I'm a legendary story" - "It is" loool

Comment: This comment makes me think if I understood "legendary" as I should ;d

Comment: - as in myths and legends, right? ;)

Comment: I think so, I was just amused by the profanity of that statement xD

Comment: I enjoyed his explanation about him not having kids, the carpenter part haha